# Sorting data based on column in javafx using handler

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

How to call the sort function without clicking on the column header?

When i am clicking on the table header, records are getting sorted. But i want to sort the records without clicking on the table header. Is it possible to add handler for column header, if so what handler do i need to call.

Comment: If you want to sort the column not triggered by a click on the column header, what should trigger the sorting? Time based, should it already be sorted? Key-combination? ...

Comment: It should be already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify [the `sortOrder` of `TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getSortOrder--) and use [the `sortType` property of `TableColum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#sortTypeProperty--).

### Example

#### Element type

```
public class Element {

    private final String a;
    private final String b;

    public Element(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

#### Constructing the `TableView`

```
    TableView<Element> tv = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Element("a", "a"),
            new Element("a", "b"),
            new Element("b", "a"),
            new Element("b", "b")));

    TableColumn<Element, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("a");
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("a"));
    column1.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);

    TableColumn<Element, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("b");
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("b"));
    column1.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);

    tv.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2);
    tv.getSortOrder().setAll(column1, column2);

    // Button reverses order of column1 on click
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Reverse column 1");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        column1.setSortType(reverse(column1.getSortType()));
    });

...

private static TableColumn.SortType reverse(TableColumn.SortType st) {
    return TableColumn.SortType.values()[1-st.ordinal()];
}
```